# Cannot find DReplay.exe for SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have been working on SQL Server 2019 version and trying to setup a load test environment using SQL Server Distributed Reply Controller - Client, however I cannot find the DReplay.exe. I thought the it will be installed as part of the installation of Distributed Reply Controller, but it didnt. Some articles suggest that it will be installed as part Management Tools from the installation media for SQL Server but the Management Tools option has been removed from the installation option.

There is also no link online to suggest an alternative way to get the DReplay.exe installed. Running out of options now.

As a desperate measure, I did try to copy the  the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn" folder content from an older server where it was installed to the new SQL Server 2019 which did not work, throwing error "Failed to load assembly...."

---

### Edit

I managed to install tools using commandline with following cmd:

```
setup.exe /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION="install" /FEATURES=Tools
```

Which resulted in installer creating a new folder 130:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130
```

It also installed the DReplay.exe file in folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn
```

Considering it is SQL Server 2019 I was expecting it to install the .exe in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn`

Anyway I tried to PreProcess my trace file using the following command and it failed and threw the following error:

### Command to PreProcess Trace Files:

```
dreplay.exe preprocess -m "Controller_Name" -i "B:\Trace\TraceFile__121359.trc" -d "B:\Trace\Output" -f 20
```

### Error:

> 2020-05-19 14:54:30:309 Error DReplay   Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make
>   sure
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DistributedReplay.ExceptionTemplates.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DistributedReplay" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

Any ideas any suggestions please?? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find it either.  I'll ask around and update here.

But. I've always had better luck with OStress from the [RML Utiltities](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4511) than the Distributed Replay feature.  So you might try that as a workaround.

Comment: HI David, thanks for your response, I have never heard of RML Utiltities until now. Can I use this to Capture work load from Production and replay on the new test server? Does it do the job ok or are there any limitations to it? Also I cannot find any documentation for it online.

Comment: It's fully capable for both workload capture and replay.   The docs are in the download.  And OStress is so fast that a single client can typically drive enough load to saturate your server.  It's widely used by SQL Server support.  See eg https://github.com/microsoft/SqlNexus/wiki/RML-Utility

Comment: Cheers David, really appreciate your help, I will give this tool a go. Thanks pal.